# Adding JSON Data to an Array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

I want to have an Array as below:

```
$scope.content = { tabs: [{ id: 1, label: "Tab 1" }, { id: 2, label: "Tab 2" }] };
```

I Receive my data using an ajax request and want to create an object and add it to $scope.content something as below:

```
 var tab = { id: 3, label: "Tab 3" };
 $scope.content["tabs"].push(tab);
```

my result should be as below:

```
 $scope.content = { tabs: [{ id: 1, label: "Tab 1" }, { id: 2, label: "Tab 2" }, { id: 3, label: "Tab 3" }] };
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify. Please check it again.

Comment: You want to know how to make an Ajax request in an angular application?

Comment: No, don't think about Ajax. I want to updated array in first paragraph to array in third paragraph

Comment: What you have should work fine.

Comment: `$scope.content` is an object and not an array. Instead it's key `tabs` is an array. So what you wrote should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have written should work, but you can access the tabs array directly and just push your new tab object into the array.

```
$scope.content.tabs.push(tab);
```